# Netplan dedicated OOB interface configuration with DHCP

Tags: networking, netplan

I have a project that deploys virtual machines as test clients.  Each VM has two NICs, one for a test environment(ens192) and one for OOB access(ens224).  Both NICs get IP addresses from DHCP.

Where I'm having trouble is in the routing. Traffic that leaves the VM is correctly taking the route out the ens192 NIC but response frames for inbound traffic to the ens224 interface is going out the test environment NIC.

I have tried assigning ens224 to a VRF via Netplan but im getting an error("Error in network definition: unknown key 'vrfs'") when trying to apply that config and I believe this is a netplan version issue.

How can I(ideally through netplan, but im open to anything) configure the VM to send all response traffic that comes inbound to ens224 back out that interface?